# How to save data in a database and open new activity after it is saved?

Tags: java, android, xml

Need help on this. When the user fills in their data and saves to the database, I want the button to open new activity after it has been saved... so far my app just saved the data and just stops on the `activity_form.xml.need` help on how to make the submit button open new activity after it saves the data would be much appreciated if someone can help me on this pleaseee. TQ.

Here is my `formActivity.java`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.util.Patterns;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.CheckBox;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.RadioButton;
        import android.widget.RadioGroup;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

        import com.android.volley.Request;
        import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.regex.Matcher;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FormActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://khaty-ismail0.rhcloud.com/phptutorial/submitData.php";
    private static final String SPINNER_URL = "http://khaty-ismail0.rhcloud.com/phptutorial/spinner_data.php";

    public static final String KEY_NAME= "Name";
    public static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String KEY_TICKET = "ticket_id";
    public static final String KEY_SOLUTION = "solution";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    String gender ="";

    private EditText name_eT;
    private EditText age_eT;
    private EditText email_eT;
    private EditText phone_eT;
    private EditText descr_eT;

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    private Button subm_btn;
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

        name_eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_eT);
        age_eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_eT);
        email_eT= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_eT);
        phone_eT= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_eT);
        descr_eT= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descr_eT);



        subm_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subm_btn);
        subm_btn.setOnClickListener(this);


        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void registerUser(){
        final String Name = name_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Age = age_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Email = email_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Phone = phone_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Description = descr_eT.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
            name_eT.setError("Please enter your name");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Age)) {
            age_eT.setError("Please enter your age");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Phone)) {
            phone_eT.setError("Please enter your phone");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
            email_eT.setError("Please enter your email");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Description)) {
            descr_eT.setError("Please enter your issue");
            return;
        }

        final RadioGroup radioGroup =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        final RadioButton male_rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.male_rb);
        final RadioButton female_rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.female_rb);

        if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()== male_rb.getId())
        {
            KEY_GENDER = "Male";
        }
        else if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==female_rb.getId()){
            KEY_GENDER = "Female";
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_NAME,Name);
                params.put(KEY_AGE,Age);
                params.put(KEY_GENDER,gender);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, Email);
                params.put(KEY_PHONE, Phone);
                params.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, Description);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View V) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) V).isChecked();

        switch (V.getId()) {
            case R.id.male_rb:
                if (checked)

                    break;

            case R.id.female_rb:
                if (checked)

                    break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == subm_btn){
            registerUser();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    /*public void submitData(View view) {
        Intent getResponse =  new Intent(this,SubmitData.class);

        final int result = 1;

        startActivityForResult(getResponse, result);
    }*/
}
```

Here is `activity_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/buttonFont"
    tools:context="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2.FormActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/User_info"
        android:id="@+id/userInfo"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:id="@+id/name_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userInfo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:id="@+id/age_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/age_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name_tV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:id="@+id/gender_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_tV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/age_tV"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:id="@+id/email_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/email_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name_tV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:id="@+id/phone_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gender_tV" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/name_eT"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userInfo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:id="@+id/age_eT"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userInfo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email_eT"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/age_eT" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_tV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email_eT" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/incident_info"
        android:id="@+id/incidentInfo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:prompt="@array/incident_type"
        android:entries="@array/incident_type"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incidentInfo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/incident_type_DD"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:id="@+id/incident_DD"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incidentInfo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:id="@+id/description_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_tV" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/descr_eT"
        android:hint="@string/descr_hint"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_tV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/description_tV" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:onClick="submitData"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:id="@+id/subm_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonFont"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_eT"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/descr_eT"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/descr_eT"
        android:layout_above="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Male"
            android:id="@+id/male_rb"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/female_rb"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the submit button to save and open another activity called `submit_data.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/buttonFont"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2.SubmitData">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Thank You for reporting to BruCERT."
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="You will be entertained within 24hours. Your information will be treated strictly confidential."
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Please retain the ticket number for quick follow up and to ensure effective response."
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the `submitData.java`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Khadijah on 3/29/2016.
 */
public class SubmitData extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.submit_data);
    }
    public void submitData(View view) {
        Intent getResponse =  new Intent(this,SubmitData.class);

        final int result = 1;

        startActivityForResult(getResponse, result);
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/brucertlogotrans"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>-->
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".FormActivity"
            android:label="Online Form">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2.FormActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SubmitData"
            android:label="Feedback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2.SubmitData" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example which shows the problem? Try to only include bits of code related to the question at hand.

Comment: there is no error in app. when the user submit data, it did save to my database.what i want is, when the user press "submit", the data successfully saved then it automatically open another layout.so far it just saved and stop at the form layout only instead if opening another xml file.

Comment: I didn't say there was an "error", but it apparently has a problem (which is why you're here). Try to remove as much code as possible until you have a much smaller example that we can help you with. No one wants to read all 500+ lines of your code, but if you cut it down--removing all the unnecessary stuff--we're more likely to look at your code. (Try to sell us on reading your question.) And, you might actually discover the issue yourself!

Comment: You should also check out the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info about asking good questions and generally how to participate on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code

```
startActivity(new Intent(FormActivity.this, SubmitData.class));
```

inside **onResponse(String response)** method. And remove submitData method from SubmitData.java file. Also remove **android:onClick="submitData"** from activity_form.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the login button call an AsyncTask, and on the onPostExecute() after validating the information, you can startActivity() to whatever Activity you want to open.